# gwt-maven-plugin appends "-linux" when getting gwt-dev artifact

Tags: linux, maven-2, gwt, nexus

I've been trying to get the gwt-maven-plugin to work for me. Hopefully someone can help me.

I'm using gwt-maven-plugin 1.2 and trying to get it to work with gwt 2.1.0.M3. We have a nexus repo at work and I've put the latest gwt jars there. The plugin fails when trying to download the gwt-dev jar.

The gwt-dev jar is located at *2.1.0.M3/gwt-dev-2.1.0.M3.jar*
The plugin tries to download  *2.1.0.M3/gwt-dev-2.1.0.M3-linux.jar*.

I don't have a dependency anywhere on my pom for gwt-dev, the plugin takes care of that. How can I stop it from appending "-linux" to it? I'm aware that I could just change the name of the jar in my repo or set it up manually on my local machine, but I want to figure out how to get this working on nexus because we have several developers working on this at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) to version 1.2, which has some support for GWT-2.0.
As of GWT-2.0, the gwt-dev jars are no longer distributed separately per platform - a fact which the older versions of the gwt-maven-plugin are not aware.

Comment: It was version 1.2 at the time of writing, but I see that version 2.1.0 has been released into the central maven repo as of 2 November. I haven't tried this new version yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. Here's what worked for me, which I gleaned from this sample pom: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/expenses/pom.xml

Add this to your plugin repos:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gwt-plugin-repo</id>
        <url>http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven</url>
        <name>Google Web Toolkit Plugin Repository</name>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Set your gwt-maven-plugin to 1.3.1.google

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.google</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

i was trying to upgrade my project to gwt 2.1, and with the things that Bohemian said and with

```
<repository>
    <id>googlecode</id>
    <url>http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/2.1.0/gwt/maven</url>
</repository>
```

i succeeded to do so.